# VUE: when emitted event call parent conponent, we can get arguments which inculdes all the parameter that emitted event pass

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I have the following code

```
// child component
this.$emit('someEvent', 1, 2, 3)
// parent component
<child @someEvent="handleSomeEvent(arguments, 5,6)"></child>
methods: {
  handleSomeEvent (arg, a, b) {
    console.log(...arg); // 1,2,3
  }
}
```

I want to know

1. How does the code work?
2. Why we can get arguments?

I don't understand the principle, I cannot find answer form source code or internet.
can anyone help me explain this, please.

Answer (score 0):

That is how `Vue emit` works:

```
vm.$emit(eventName, [...args])
```

Arguments will be passed into the listener’s callback function. Everything passed after `emitName` will be assumed as `arguments`.
Here is the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware the use of `arguments` in an inline event handler is not documented. You can achieve something similar using an explicit function without resorting to `arguments`:

```
@someEvent="(a, b, c) => { handleSomeEvent(a, b, c, 5, 6) }"
```

or:

```
@someEvent="(...args) => { handleSomeEvent(args, 5, 6) }"
```

As for why using `arguments` works, the relevant source code is here:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/fd0eaf92948bb5a4882d538362091fb287d642e3/src/compiler/codegen/events.js#L161

I highly recommend studying the source of `genHandler`. Vue uses it to generate the listener function based on the `v-on` attribute value.

In summary, when you write this:

```
@someEvent="handleSomeEvent(arguments, 5, 6)"
```

Vue will generate a handler function like this:

```js
function ($event) {
  handleSomeEvent(arguments, 5, 6)
}
```

Then when you call `$emit` the parameters you pass to `$emit` (apart from the event name) will be the arguments passed to this function. The identifier `arguments` behaves just like it would inside any other JavaScript function.

I would note that the exact form of the handler function Vue generates varies depending on the form of the `v-on` attribute. It uses some regular expressions to decide what type of handler to generate. You'll find all that code in `genHandler`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'll spend time to study `genHandler`.